# Grep to filter log file

Tags: shell, grep

How to change a log file that looks like this:

```
Jul 6 17:35:10 sdc-prius motion_planner[1284]: new destination: [55.733510, 37.587401]
Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733668, 37.587143] 
Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 212, throttle: 420
Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 145, throttle: 634
Jul 6 17:35:12 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 65, throttle: 538
Jul 6 17:35:13 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733948, 37.586731] 
Jul 6 17:35:13 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 121, throttle: 340
Jul 6 17:35:13 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 150, throttle: 600
Jul 6 17:35:14 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 46, throttle: 346
Jul 6 17:35:13 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733955, 37.586744] 
Jul 6 17:35:13 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 485, throttle: 567
Jul 6 17:35:13 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.734094, 37.586518]
Jul 6 17:35:14 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 278, throttle: 400 
Jul 6 17:35:14 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.734300, 37.586229]
Jul 6 17:35:14 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 982, throttle: 400 
Jul 6 17:35:14 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.734530, 37.585896]
Jul 6 17:35:14 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 98, throttle: 400 
Jul 6 17:35:15 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733948, 37.586731]
Jul 6 17:35:15 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 33, throttle: 200 
Jul 6 17:35:15 sdc-prius motion_planner[1284]: new destination: [55.734839, 37.585531]
Jul 6 17:35:15 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 2, throttle: 100
```

but needs to be like:

```
Jul 6 17:35:11 37.587143, 55.733668
Jul 6 17:35:13 37.586731, 55.733948
Jul 6 17:35:13 37.586744, 55.733955
Jul 6 17:35:13 37.586518, 55.734094
Jul 6 17:35:14 37.586229, 55.734300
Jul 6 17:35:14 37.585896, 55.734530
Jul 6 17:35:15 37.586731, 55.733948
```

I was able to go as far as:

```
grep -o '^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\s\d\s\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\|\[\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\d\,\s\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\d\]' test.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change a log file"?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the reordering of the fields, you won't be able to do this with `grep`, but `sed` will do the job.

Given that you already have a reasonable grasp of regular expressions, you should find it straightforward to mark the source fields and reorder them in the replacement, although `sed` does not recognise `\d` to match a digit.

The following simplified match works on your test data:

```
sed -En 's/^(.*) sdc-.*\[.*\].*\[(.*), (.*)\]/\1 \3, \2/p' test.txt
```

The `(` and `)` delimit fields, with `\N` (where `N` is `1` to `9`) denoting fields in the replacement string.

[This](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) is a good introduction to `sed`.